# Scrapping <a> along with <p> using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am a journalist by profession and learned python for news article scrapping. Using BeautifulSoup I am able to get

patagraphs from a news website however if there is a paragraph with a hyperlink , it does not scrap that line of text. Is there anyway I can get that line of text too?

`!pip3 install requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import requests as req
import io

```
url = "https://www.geo.tv/latest/456848-ronaldo-eyes-world-cup-quarters-as-morocco-dare-to-dream"
webpage = req.get(url)
trav = BS(webpage.content, "html.parser")
M = 1
attributes_container = []

for link in trav.find_all('p'):
    
    # PASTE THE CLASS TYPE THAT WE GET
    # FROM THE ABOVE CODE IN THIS
    if(str(type(link.string)) == "<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>"
    and len(link.string) > 35):
        x=str(link.string)
        print (x)
        attributes_container.append(x)
        
text_df = pd.DataFrame(attributes_container, columns=["Text"])
text_df
```

`

In this case for example, the news article has "Cristiano Ronaldo" as a hyperlink so that line does not get scrraped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `.text`. It will consider every text under that tag. Also, to ensure that irrelevant text will not include in your list, you should only focus on the specific `div` (i.e., class `content-area`).

```
content_area = trav.find("div", {"class": "content-area"})
attributes_container = []

for link in content_area.find_all('p'):
    text = link.text
    if len(text) > 35:
        print(text)
        attributes_container.append(text)
```

output:

```
                                                 Text
0   DOHA: Cristiano Ronaldo will aim to fire Portu...
1   Just two last-eight slots remain to be filled ...
2   Ronaldo was hogging the headlines at the tourn...
3   Following an exit by "mutual agreement" he is ...
4   The 37-year-old superstar forward, who is appe...
5   After scoring a penalty in his team's opening ...
6                                                ....
```